# Create a customized EventLog logname

Tags: c#, .net, service, event-log

I am trying to create my customized [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx) for my service. I was able to customize my `source` but not not the `logName` by using [CreateEventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a(v=vs.110).aspx) method. In my service constructor:

```
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "MySource", "MyNewLog");
            }

            eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
            eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
        }
```

I was able to customize `MySource` to whatever I want, but whenever I change `MyNewLog`, my service crashes because this `eventLog1` is writing specifically to `MyNewLog` in the Event Viewer. [This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/working-with-eventviewer-using-C-Sharp-for-beginners/) shows you how to check if a [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx) [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d7bfbtc(v=vs.110).aspx) and how to [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2ch3468(v=vs.110).aspx) it. But, how do I CREATE a customized EventLog?

Comment: are you running this under an Admin account?  you need privs...

Comment: Yes, I am. Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to even customize my SourceName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out how to create a new `EventLog` inside `Applications and Services Logs`. According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx),

> The source cannot be registered because it already exists on the local computer.

So it was my mistake that I didn't know  you have to create a **NEW** source when you **create** a new log, that is to say, you cannot have an existing source inside a new log.